# Difference between `while ... end` and `while ... do ... end`

Tags: ruby, syntax

What's the difference between:

```
x = 1
while x < 5 do
  x += 1
  print x
end
```

and:

```
x = 1
while x < 5
  x += 1
  print x
end
```

whereby `do` is added to the first one? Or, is there difference?

Comment: It’s optional: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop

Comment: I assume you got your example from [this Techtopia page](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_While_and_Until_Loops) on "Ruby While and Until Loops" because the example code is the exact same. On that page it lays it out for you: "The `do` in this case is actually optional." [More detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029352/3784008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference when you include the newline between the while loop declaration and the code. So:

```
while flag
    #code here
end
```

is the same as:

```
while flag do
    #code here
end
```

However, when you include `do`, you can put code on the same line, as in:

```
while flag do myMethod() end
```

Comment: Similar to `if ... then` vs. `if ...` where the `then` is optional.

Comment: For a one-liner you'd use `myMethod() while flag`

Answer (score 3):

It is just used to separate the actual loop code.

> A while loop's conditional is separated from code by the reserved word
>   do, a newline, backslash \, or a semicolon ;.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: Cite your source when quoting, please.